# Typecast to a FLOAT

Tags: casting, floating-point, mariadb, mysql-8.0

The following query was not returning my expected/desired results for `slope` and `intercept`.  I finally realized that `slope` and `intercept` are typecasted as integers in my anchor query, and remain integers through the recursion.

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
    SELECT id parentId, idPublic parentIdPublic, name parentName,
           slope parentSlope, intercept parentIntercept,
    id, idPublic, name, type, 1 slope, 0 intercept, value
    FROM measurements
    WHERE id IN (414,415,416,417,491)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.parentId, t.parentIdPublic, t.parentName,
           t.parentSlope, t.parentIntercept,
           m.id, m.idPublic, m.name, m.type,
           t.slope*pchm.sign*m.slope slope,
           t.intercept+t.slope*pchm.sign*m.intercept intercept, m.value
    FROM t
    INNER JOIN subpoints sp ON sp.measurementId=t.id
    INNER JOIN measurements m ON m.id=sp.measurementId
)
SELECT slope, intercept FROM t;
```

`slope` and `intercept` needs to be able to store widely different values and exact accuracy is not important, so I feel a `FLOAT` is best.  My schema for `slope` and `intercept` is as shown:

```
`slope` FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
`intercept` FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
```

As a hack solution, I changed my anchor query to:

```
SELECT id parentId, ..., 1.0 slope, 0.0 intercept, value
```

I think the right solution is to typecase these two values to a `FLOAT`, but the documentation does not seem to allow.  I could do `DECIMAL`, however, I have the issue with `slope` and `intercept` potentially being a wide range of values.

Am I able to cast `slope` and `intercept` to `FLOAT`?  If not, what is the best solution?

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0+?

Comment: @RaymondNijland  Server version: 10.2.13-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Comment: @RaymondNijland  MariaDB is a fork of MySQL.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info states not to use the MySQL tag for other database questions such as SQL Server and SQLite, but doesn't preclude MariaDB and actually states that it is related.  Why did you edit my post and remove the MySQL tag?

Comment: "MariaDB is a fork of MySQL" i know MariaDB is a fork off MySQL.. "Why did you edit my post and remove the MySQL tag? " Because you said you are using MariaDB 10.2 under the MariaDB tag only you can get better help. Besides MySQL 8.0+ is the closest thing MySQL has to over offer too support CTE's but MySQL 8.0+ isn't production ready jet..

Comment: @RaymondNijland.  I've since changed it to `CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(12,4)) slope, CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(12,4)) intercept`.  Again, this is not ideal but don't know what options I have.

Comment: If you wish to markdown my question, that is fine, but please provide a reason so I may edit and modify the question.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* that `UNION` is the villain, not `WITH`, etc.  `UNION` likes to define the datatypes based on the *first* `SELECT`.  Of course, with `WITH RECURSIVE`, you don't have the option of swapping the `SELECTs`.

So...  I vote for your 'hack solution' of 0.0 and 1.0.  Or, these might be clearer:  0e0 and 1e0.  (Still a kludge, but it points at `FLOAT`, not `DECIMAL`.)

I, too, have bemoaned the absence of `CASTing` to `FLOAT` (or `DOUBLE`).

Comment: Thanks Rick,  Yeah, I am sure that `UNION` is likely the instigator.  Odd that one can't `CAST` to `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.